# What is a shim in asdf

Tags: linux, shim, asdf

I can see that asdf is based on shim, there are commands to reshim, check the shims. Sometimes the shims are not what I expect (ex. I installed awscli and python plugin, the pip3 shim comes from awscli and not python).

Not clear what is a shim in asdf context, no explanation found on their website.
Thx

Comment: Basically, a wrapper which sets up the correct environment for the wrapped script and then runs it.